# Huawei Map Kit - Crashing click the back button

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Hello i integrated Huawei Map Kit with mapView.
But crashing when I clicking the back button.
What could be reason?

Comment: Can you post stacktrace of crash?

Answer (score 0):

If you use onDestroy() or onStop() method remove it and rebuild gradle and run project

Answer (score 0):

The sample code of onDestroy() and onStop() could be found at https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSMapKit/index.html#5

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mMapView.onStop();
}
 
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}
```